# Weird error compiling code that calls Surface low-level CUDA API

Tags: cuda, nvcc

This minimal example:

```
int main() 
{
    struct surfaceReference* surfaceReferencePointer;
    cudaGetSurfaceReference(&surfaceReferencePointer, "surfaceReference"); 
}
```

Fails when it is compiled like this:

```
nvcc -g -arch=sm_20 -o foo.out foo.cu
```

Showing the following error message:

```
foo.cu(4): warning: argument of type "surfaceReference **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const surfaceReference **"
foo.cu(4): warning: argument of type "surfaceReference **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const surfaceReference **"

foo.cu: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cu:4: error: invalid conversion from ‘surfaceReference**’ to ‘const surfaceReference**’
foo.cu:4: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘cudaError_t cudaGetSurfaceReference(const surfaceReference**, const char*)’
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. I am compiling on a Linux Ubuntu 64-bit machine, using CUDA 3.2.

Comment: You should define you pointer as *const*

Comment: You're right! Please, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `struct surfaceReference*` pointer should be defined as `const`:

```
int main() 
{
    const struct surfaceReference* surfaceReferencePointer;
    cudaGetSurfaceReference(&surfaceReferencePointer, "surfaceReference"); 
}
```

Kudos to [**codymanix**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44952/codymanix), who provided the right answer in the comments.